# Accessing mapping inside object with web3.js

Tags: web3js, arrays, mapping

Good day.

I have a struct object called HomeWork

```
HomeWork[] public homeworks;

struct HomeWork{
    uint256 assignId;
    string description;
    mapping(address=>uint256)handedAt;
    mapping(address=>bool)passedOrFailed;

};
```

As you can see, this object contains nested mappings inside.

I'm trying to interact with this object using web3.

```
contract = web3.eth.contract([ABI]).at("0x0..");
var homeworks = contract.homeworks();
```

But when I'm examining specific instance, I can't get any information about the mappings:

> [>homeworks(2)]
>
> [>BigNumber, "this is description for item number 3"]  *** there should be 2 mappings here ***

That's it. the mappings aren't there at all.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible for mappings. In your case you can only access the assignId and description of your struct doing contract.homeworks(index);

If you want to "fix" it you should write your custom getter function.

Here is what the doc says :

> Accessor Functions
>   The compiler automatically creates accessor functions for all public state variables. The contract given below will have a function called data that does not take any arguments and returns a uint, the value of the state variable data. The initialization of state variables can be done at declaration.
>
> The accessor functions have external visibility. If the symbol is accessed internally (i.e. without this.), it is a state variable and if it is accessed externally (i.e. with this.), it is a function.

```
contract test {
   uint public data = 42;
}
```

> The next example is a bit more complex:

```
contract complex {
  struct Data { uint a; bytes3 b; mapping(uint => uint) map; }
  mapping(uint => mapping(bool => Data[])) public data;
}
```

> It will generate a function of the following form:

```
function data(uint arg1, bool arg2, uint arg3) returns (uint a, bytes3 b)

{
  a = data[arg1][arg2][arg3].a;
  b = data[arg1][arg2][arg3].b;
}
```

> **Note that the mapping in the struct is omitted because there is no good way to provide the key for the mapping.**